# What is the reason to specify [0] in $(this)[0] expression, when inside an Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

i currently learning jquery and i came across this code in my tutorial:

```
$('textarea').scroll(function(){
    var y = $('textarea')[0].scrollHeight;
    var x = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
});
```

My question is about the [0]
I understand that the $('textarea') is an array, and it make sense to add [0] if i want only the scrollHeight of the first element.
But when i m **inside an Event Handler than $(this) is by definition a single element**
(The element which is currently being scrolled).
So why should i specify the [0]th object, where $(this) is a clearly a single object and not an array at all
Thank you
ps. if you downvote pls comment the reason

Comment: Yeah, don't do `$(this)[0]` as it's pointless to make that jQuery object.  And jQuery objects are not arrays.  They are "array like"

Comment: I would start looking for another tutorial.

Comment: learn.jquery.com and try.jquery.com are good resources for beginners

Comment: The primary reason [0] is used in this case is because the property the dev wanted to look at isn't available on a jquery collection, but it is available on a dom node. since `this` is already a dom node, there was no reason to make it a jquery collection in the first place.

Comment: To be clear, you can just do `this.scrollHeight` instead of `$(this)[0].scrollHeight`

Comment: If i do only $(this).scrollHeight code doesnt work!

Comment: the [0] on the jquery object is a direct access to the actual html element.  you can then use that to access native javascript properties on the element.   its the same as document.getElementById(XX)

Comment: Right, because jQuery does not expose the underlying dom properties directly.  To get a dom property off a jQuery object you'd use `prop(propertyName)` such as `prop('scrollHeight')`

Comment: A better way (if you don't already just have the dom object) would be to use `$("'textarea").get(0).scrollHeight` and `this.scrollHeight` https://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Summary of the various points made in the comments.

If you have a single DOM element and you want to access a property off of it, there is no reason to do `$(element)[0].property` as the [0] simply gets the first element off of the jQuery result stack, which was the single element you gave it.

If you are performing a query and you want to get a property off of one of them there are a few ways to do this.

```
//get the 5th element off the stack and access the property
$(selector)[4].property
//get the 5th element off the stack, with the jQuery method, and access the property
$(selector).get(4).property
//get the 5th element off the stack, as a jQuery object still, and get the property with the jQuery method
$(selector).eq(4).prop('property')
```

Comment: thank you. pls upvote my question if you think it is SO worthy